# Add column to aspnetusers with database first

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have found many tutorials for adding columns to the Identity tables (which I have successfully moved to the application database) with database migrations however my understanding is this is not applicable in database fist projects. So...how do I add columns to the aspnetusers table in a database first project?

I would like to ad a bit type column called Is RegComplete which is initially set to 0 then at some point when the user has completed some more tasks then set to 1.

Comment: I still can't seem to crack this. It looks like there maybe a number of issues being a) the emdx does not contain the identity tables and I am not sure they re supposed to and b) I can't update the database though migrations as I have moved the tables to the application database which we done using database first. I have looked for some documentation on this but they all refer to code-first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I've cracked it! Firstly I didn't realise that although I have moved the Identity tables to the Application database there is still two Database Contexts, one for the application tables which are DB First, and the other for the Identities tables.

I was able to enable migrations and add the column using code first and migrate then update the database. The new column is now available in the controller.

I found this tutorial which helped me: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx

Comment: hi. do you still use both contexts, or just one for everything?

Comment: I am using two context to the same database one for user/identity tables and one for the application tables.

Comment: This article is excelent very helpful! https://www.apress.com/gp/blog/all-blog-posts/secular-trends-for-the-cloud/12097630. Important when adding to an existng Data Base.

Comment: public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser 
{ 
//example
public String Name { get; set; } 
....
}

Answer (score 3):

**The easiest solution:**

- Add columns into `AspNetUsers` table
- Add properties into `IdentityModels.cs` class (Check attachment)
- Add same properties into `AccountViewModels.cs\RegisterViewModel` class
- Compile and it will work.

**Attachment**
[image]

**(VS 2017, MVC5)**

Comment: `Add properties into IdentityModels.cs class (Check attachment)`, based on your attachment image, it should be `ApplicationUser` class that is inherent from `IdentityUser`. Anyway +1