# Auto filled column with Code First and no POCO property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Identity for my project.

I created a new column directly in the database in `AspNetUsers` called `CreationDate` and defined that its default value would be the current date and it's stored as expected.

The problem is that if I generate the database again I will need to create this column again. I mean, in production or in a new environment.

I want to know if it's possible to use the *[fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)* in a way I can define it in the `OnModelCreating` (with its default value).

The class is inside Identity classes from the template ASP.NET creates (`ApplicationDbContext`, `ApplicationUser` and so on) and I want to know if this is possible by using directly the *fluent API* (and not inheritance or [creating all the classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162248/add-column-to-aspnetusers-with-database-first)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the property to the **ApplicationUser** class if you want to manipulate it with the Fluent API. I dont understand why you don't want to extend the default properties in **ApplicationUser**. Adding **CreationDate** as a property there will create a column :

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    //This is the property that will match your column
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType)
    {

        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);

        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to extend the classe just because I don't really need in any other aspect. This column would possibly be seen just in the database with no need for a `View` to this. I understand your solution but I was thinking if it would be possible to create a column in the Fluent API with no references in the code (apart from its creation).

Comment: The idea behind EF is that your database can be syncronized with your model (in order to do that, EF has to know every single object in your Db). Just because you don't need to show that property in the view doesn't mean you don't need to have it in your code. Persistence and presentation has nothing to do with each other. I suggest you to add it to your code instead of having to create an sql script that runs every time after you create the db (plus you get source control this way).